# Why do ropes store data only at the leafs?

Tags: data-structures

If you look at the definition of a rope on wikipedia:

> A rope is a binary tree where each leaf (end node) holds a string and a length (also known as a "weight"), and each node further up the tree holds the sum of the lengths of all the leaves in its left subtree

Why did a rope for strings end up with data only at the leaf nodes?
Is there a reason why you wouldn't, for example, use an avl and store strings at every node in the tree?

Comment: The Ropes paper spends several paragraphs just discussing the pros, cons, trade-offs, alternatives, constraints, and design decisions of the underlying data structure. It would help focus your question, if you could explain, *precisely* which parts of that you disagree with or don't understand.

Comment: Also, note this: "It is not clear whether the implementation we suggested above is in any sense optimal. However, it performs sufficiently well for our purposes". So, IOW, the authors are fully aware that there may be better ways to implement Ropes, they just haven't found a reason.